# Does anyone have a strategy for Call of Duty Black Ops Zombie mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, cod-black-ops-zombies

I realize there is no point to the zombie mode except to see how long you can last; but we play this game like crazy. I was wondering if anyone has any tips on how to last longer. We consistently last to round 10. once we get the power on we don't really know what to do from there. we run around and turn on traps but it doesn't seem like there's really anything else to do. what is the point of the transporter? and when you look at the map on the wall and the green light appears, what does that mean?

Comment: The strategy would be different for each map, which map are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The transporter takes you (and your party if applicable) to a room with the PACK A PUNCH machine, which will upgrade any weapon you put into it into a new (usually better) version of that weapon. If memory serves properly it costs 5000 per weapon upgraded this way.

The green light on the map is where the 'Box' is. The 'Box' is an awesome little contraption where you feed it 950 points and it gives you a random weapon. The 'Box' has a craptton of weapons that you CANNOT OTHERWISE get from the walls. You always want to find and use the box until you get your weapon of choice, and since your rather new (level 10 ain't nuthin, talk to some people who get to the upper 70s), I wont spoil some of the AWESOME weapons the box can give you, I'll just say keep using it and eventually you will be pleasantly surprised.

As for lasting longer most people use either a 'red' or 'blue' route. Which is to say, they only open one half of the available areas and run in a big circle around the compound.

[image: Map of Red and Blue routes]

That pic should help you understand what I mean. Generally one stands on the stage until the waves start coming, makes their way from the stage to the starting room, then either up the stairs or out to the alleyway. Only stop to shoot your pursuers in the starting room as they all crowd around the 'island' right outside the door to the auditorium, as thats arguably the best choke point in the level. If you have friends a good idea is to designate 2 of you to watch for oncoming zombies while the other 2 mow down your pursuers. Make sure you reguarly trade off jobs so everyone gets points for the Pack a Punch. If you need more thoughts or ideas or tips feel free to drop a comment or if applicable a whole new question if you need a different topic answered.

Edit:  I totally forgot about the soda's. After you turn the power on you can purchase 4 different sodas from machines scattered about the map, and these sodas give you perks when purchased. They are marked on the map with < P >. Of all of these JUGGERNOG is probably the most important and a MUST HAVE once the power is turned on. It costs 2500 I think, (its been awhile since I specifically played black ops zombies), and severely increases the amount of punishment you can take before the zombies take you down, allowing for the occasional mistake as you run.
The other perks gained from the sodas are also usefull but not as usefull as JUGGERNOG.
Note: When playing solo, the quick revive perk which is available in the starting room, is always active, even with the power off. And unlike the multiplayer version which makes it so you can revive your friends faster, in solo mode it makes it so you can revive yourself when you go down, however you can only buy it 3 times in any given solo game.